# How to slowly fade background color from white to red in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the background color to fade red when `allowDrop003(event)` is called.

myjs.js:

```
function allowDrop003(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

        // fade background color from default to color red 
}
```

.html:

```
<body style="background-color:white">
        <div style="height:200px">
            <div class="MyClass1" ondrop="drop001(event)">
                <img ondragstart="dragStart001(event)" draggable="true" id="target001" src='img-src'>
            </div>
            <div class="MyClass" ondrop="drop006(event)" ondragover="allowDrop003(event)" id="place001">square</div>
        </div>
</body>
```

I'm thinking about setting `background-color` to red first with `opacity = 0`, then after `allowDrop003(event)` is called, change `opacity` back to 1. Anybody has a solution for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

With Javascript use [ClassList](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp) to Add/Remove (or Toggle) a class like `fadeOut` and add some CSS3 to handle opacity and animation:

```
.MyClass {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.MyClass.fadeOut {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Now you just have to create [Javascript events](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp) and call function who add and remove the `fadeOut` class.

I create an example with simple click event on "Square" text who will toggle the red box opacity:

```js
const myClass = document.querySelector('.MyClass');
const myClass1 = document.querySelector('.MyClass1');

myClass.addEventListener('click', () => {
  myClass1.classList.toggle('fadeOut')
});
```

```css
.img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background:red;
}
.MyClass1 {
 opacity: 1;
 transition: opacity .5s;
}
.MyClass1.fadeOut {
 opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:white">
        <div style="height:50px">
            <div class="MyClass1" ondrop="drop001(event)">
                <div class="img"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="MyClass" ondrop="drop006(event)" ondragover="allowDrop003(event)" id="place001">square</div>
        </div>
</body>
```